# Nullable<T> confusion

Tags: c#, generics, nullable

Why is the following forbidden?

```
Nullable<Nullable<int>>
```

whereas

```
struct MyNullable <T>
{


}

MyNullable<Nullable<int>>
```

is NOT

Comment: What would a Nullable<Nullable<int>> even mean?

Comment: To be fair, "meaning" is a bit irrelevant here. You shouldn't read anything into the names of things, because the compiler doesn't.  But what *is* different here is that the CLR treats System.Nullable<T> as a special type and handles certain operations on it differently.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

This is because the struct constraint actually means ['not nullable'](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fsdhc71f(VS.80).aspx) since Nullable, despite being a struct, is nullable (can accept the value null) the `Nullable<int>` is not a valid type parameter to the outer Nullable.

This is made explicit in [the constraints documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx)

> where T: struct
>   The type argument must be a value type. Any value type except Nullable can be specified.
>   See Using Nullable Types (C# Programming Guide) for more information.

If you want the rationale for that you would need the actual language designer's comments on it which I can't find. However I would postulate that:

1. the compiler and platform changes required to achieve Nullable in it's current form are quite extensive (and were a relatively last minute addition to the 2.0 release).
2. They have several potentially confusing edge cases.

Allowing the equivalent of int?? would only confuse that since the language provides no way of distinguishing Nullable`<Nullable<null>>` and Nullable`<null>` nor any obvious solution to the following.

```
Nullable<Nullable<int>> x = null;
Nullable<int> y = null;
Console.WriteLine(x == null); // true
Console.WriteLine(y == null); // true
Console.WriteLine(x == y); // false or a compile time error!
```

Making that return true would be **very** complex and significant overhead on many operations involving the Nullable type.

Some types in the CLR are 'special', examples are strings and primitives in that the compiler and runtime know a lot about the implementation used by each other. Nullable is  special in this way as well. Since it is already special cased in other areas special casing the `where T : struct` aspect is not such a big deal. The benefit of this is in dealing with structs in generic classes because none of them, apart from Nullable, can be compared against null. This means the jit can safely consider `t == null` to be false always.

Where languages are designed to allow two very different concepts to interact you tend to get weird, confusing or down right dangerous edge cases. As an example consider Nullable and  the equality operators

```
int? x = null;
int? y = null;
Console.WriteLine(x == y); // true
Console.WriteLine(x >= y); // false!
```

By preventing Nullables when using struct generic constraint many nasty (and unclear) edge cases can be avoided.

As to the exact part of the specification that mandates this [from section 25.7](http://en.csharp-online.net/ECMA-334:_25.7_Constraints) (emphasis mine):

> The value type constraint specifies that a type argument used for the type parameter
>   must be a value type (§25.7.1). Any non-nullable struct type, enum type, or type
>   parameter having the value type constraint satisfies this constraint. A type parameter
>   having the value type constraint shall not also have the constructor-constraint. 
>   The System.Nullable type specifies the non-nullable value type constraint for T.
>   **Thus, recursively constructed types of the forms T?? and Nullable`<`Nullable`<`T`>>` are prohibited.**

Comment: Would you succinctly describe why "Any value type except Nullable can be specified" is TRUE, or provide a reference?

Comment: why they made the decision I have expanded on. The specific 'You can't because we say so' part is in the already linked documetation on the struct constraint (link 2) the 25.7 section of the spec states this clearly

Comment: Your explanation for why x.ToString() does not throw an exception is not quite right; a boxed Nullable<int> is in fact null.  Check the MSIL for what's going on.  Other than that, this answer is spot on.

Comment: hopefully a better example - more obviously bizarre too. thanks

Comment: Out of curiosity, would there have been any problem with making Nullable<T> a reference type effectively synonymous with a boxed T?  Aside from the facts that (1) the IsValueType reports true for a nullable type, (2) non-null boxed value types require a heap object to hold the data, while nullable value types use extra storage within the type itself; (3) nullable types are not permitted for class-constrained generics, what semantic differences are there between nullable and boxed types?

Comment: @supercat, remember the CLR and c# understand Nullable<T> and can convert between null and default(Nullable<T>). If it were a reference type you would have some real issues with that. Also if it being a reference type was acceptable simply going with the boxed form would likely have been acceptable for many cases. If someone has a type with value copy semantics they may have also desired the other behaviours like inline allocation within a class/array and they likely wouldn't appreciate it being made into a reference type whereever it has used in a nullable context.

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk: If nullable value types were mutable, the semantics would be very different from those of reference types.  Aside from memory usage, however, I can't think of any semantic differences between *immutable* value types and immutable reference types; since nullable types aren't exactly space-efficient to begin with, I'm not sure the memory would be a big issue.  The system likes convert value types to reference types (boxing) in enough other contexts where it actually does create problems, I'm not sure I see a problem with boxing nullable types.

Comment: @supercat the overhead for an array of lots of them would be a big deal as you would a) have the object overhead of 8 bytes compared to the 4 byte packing on the nullable). plus the reference (4 or 8 bytes) in the array itself. b) the hassle of then going to the heap for all the individual ones rather than their being in line. Yes to a reasonable number of people this wouldn't matter but to many (including me) it would.

Comment: @supercat obviously you can ignore the difference between value and reference copy semantics for immutable types. The underlying performance differences would remain however. I wouldn't like the sublte addition of a '?' to change the allocation profile of my methods (especially since it isn't clear at use site with things like literal assignment if the variable is a class variable) . I may be more picky that most in this regard because such things matter to me a lot.

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk: If one copies a non-nullable variable independently to several different nullable variables, having them stored as value types would avoid having to box them independently.  On the other hand, if a value were copied to a reference-type nullable double and that were in turn copied to other ones, the references would take four bytes each, whereas value-type doubles would take eight bytes.  I think the strongest argument for implementing nullable types as value types is the implicit conversion from value types to the nullable types at the call site.

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk: I personally find the implicit conversion of mutable value types into reference types is far more evil than any conversion of immutable value types to reference types.  Mutable value types, contrary to what Eric Lippert claims, are not evil, and have useful semantics that can't be achieved as efficiently other ways.  I I've sometimes wished for a Boxed<T> which would be generally usable as a T, but would not require additional boxing when cast to an interface; such a thing could achieve semantics very similar to Nullable<T>.

Comment: @supercat. I wholly disagree that mutable value types are not evil. Sometimes they are a *necessary* evil, mainly due to the current JIT not being capable of stack allocating (or entirely en-registering) reference types consistently. And I have been forced to do this on occasion. Evil none the less.

Comment: @supercat "the references would take four bytes each" you are not thinking in terms of 64bit, you are also assuming that there will be multiple references to the same instance a lot (the object header overhead would account for needing at least 3 of them). There is also the issue of poor memory locality (something that can make far more of a difference).

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk: Suppose I have an array of some structure type, and I pass an element by reference to some routine.  That routine can use the reference to do whatever it wants to that element, but the reference will be destroyed when the routine returns.  To achieve similar semantics using only reference types, one would have to create a new instance of a wrapper class which wouldn't expose the target object, but would instead explicitly perform any desired operations on it, and the new instance would have to be manually invalidated once the routine returned.  Vastly clunkier and less efficient.

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk: There are coding scenarios where a structure combining an 'is valid' flag and a value make sense, but I really doubt that such scenarios represent the majority usage cases for nullable types.  I would expect that most uses of nullable types are either things like temporary data storage of stuff being read from databases (in which case RAM efficiency is really not a factor) or large-scale storage situations where another means of handling "nullability" would make more sense (e.g. either a packed binary array of validity flags, or special sentinel values like NaN for real).

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk: I guess what bothers me most about nullable types is that they box to null.  I would guess this was necessitated by the design of Object.Equals; if Object.Equals would compare a null object and a non-null object by calling the non-null object's Equals method, then nullable types wouldn't need special boxing handling.

Comment: If you want such behaviour it is trivial to create a Wrapping struct with the same semantics that wraps the array. In fact @Eric did just that: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2011/03/10/references-and-pointers-part-two.aspx obviously you would simply eliminate all the arithmetic parts if you didn't want that aspect of it.

Comment: @supercat. we appear to have triggered the warning on extended discussion in comments. I shall leave this allone now.

Comment: @ShuggyCoUk: Re mutable structures, I have created chat room http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2786/mutable-value-types-are-not-evil if anyone would like to join me there.  The code you linked exposes the object references within the array, so passing an outside method an ArrayPtr object referencing an array of mutable objects will forevermore allow outside code to mutate objects in that array.

Answer (score 14):

I believe you can only use non-nullable value types in `Nullable`s.  Since `Nullable` itself is nullable, nesting this way is prohibited.

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwxxazwb.aspx

> ```
> public Nullable(
>     T value
> )
> ```
>
> Type: T A value type.

Comment: Nullable is still a value type. it is just a nullable one

Comment: You're right.  Didn't realize that.  I assumed that since it could be compared to null, it had to be a ref type, but it's a struct.  I corrected my answer.

Comment: common misunderstanding judging by the other answers :)

Answer (score 3):

Nullable is special because there's explicit support for boxing and unboxing of Nullable types built into the CLR:

If you use the MSIL `box` instruction against a `Nullable<T>`, you will actually get a `null` as the result.  There's no other value type which will produce a null when boxed.

There's similar and symmetrical support for unboxing.

Comment: Cool, it is special, but it doesn't answer the question why it is allowed.

Comment: Why *which* is allowed?  Nullable<Nullable<int>> is clearly *not* allowed, and it's because the "specialness" of Nullable is incompatible with doing so.  MyNullable<Nullable<int>> is allowed because there's no conflict with the CLR's special handling.

Answer (score 2):

The generic type parameter for Nullable must itself be a non-nullable type (i.e. value type). This is the C# compiler warning I get, and it would seem to make sense. Tell me, why would you want to do such a thing anyway? I personally can see no use, and little meaning to such a declaration even.

Comment: I frequently use bool? when I might have a true / false / unknown state. Very valid when coming from the SQL world.

Comment: It have no intention of using it, I just feel that it violates similar constrain for a different value type generic. Is Nullable special here?

Comment: Heh, I think you'd need to relearn how to program if you ever felt a desire to implement such a thing...

Comment: @Robinson, But a nullable nullable bool?  That's what the question is asking for.  I see the benefits of a three value bool (true, false, filenotfound).

Comment: @Sasha: I wouldn't say Nullable is that special here (although it does have a built-in language feature in C#). Generic type constraints aren't terribly common, but not exceedingly rare either (you can create them yourself using the "where" clause on type declarations).

Comment: Yeah, "three-valued bools" can indeed be useful (see ternary/fuzzy logic for examples), but the case of four-valued bools would seem rather pointless (besides being terrible design practice).

Comment: @Noldorin: why don't you tell this to Jon Skeet (@jonskeet), as this example was taken from his book. just a thought

Answer (score 0):

Nullable allows you to take a value type and make it like a reference type, in the sense that the value either exists or not (is null).  Since a reference type is already nullable it is not allowed.

Quoted from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx):

> The Nullable(T) structure supports
>   using only a value type as a nullable
>   type because reference types are
>   nullable by design.

Comment: it doesn't make it like a reference type, it just gives it an additional special value and compiler support for same. copy semantics remain (the major difference)

Comment: @Shuggy -- quoting again from the same reference: Represents an object whose underlying type is a value type that can also be assigned a null reference (Nothing in Visual Basic) like a reference type.

Comment: that is the only way it is like it, with considerable compiler magic to make it happen. Your answer is misleading in that it implies it makes it a reference type, in fact it is the struct constraint that is special cased.